# jOOQ - Fluent trigger builder API?

Tags: java, sql, jooq

Is there any **fluent "create trigger" builder**? It's weird but I can't find any trigger builder example (also searched in the [jOOQ manual](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/) but without success).

I would like to transform hard-coded statement:

```
"CREATE TRIGGER " + TRIGGER_DELETE_TAB + " " +
"BEFORE DELETE ON " + TABLE_TABS + " " +
"BEGIN " +
"DELETE FROM " + TABLE_CHORDNAMES + " " +
"WHERE " + CHORDNAME_TAB + " = " + "OLD."+TAB_ID +"; " +
"END;"
```

in something like that:

```
SQLiteDSL.createTrigger(TRIGGER_DELETE_TAB)
    .beforeDeleteOn(TABLE_TABS)
    .begin()
    .deleteFrom(TABLE_CHORDNAMES)
    .where(column(CHORDNAME_TAB).eq("OLD."+TAB_ID))
    .end()
    .getSQL();
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jOOQ could contain an API to implement a really trivial trigger like yours seems to be, and chances are, it will in some future version ([#6956](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6956)).

But in order to fully support triggers, jOOQ needs a runtime model abstracting over all sorts of procedural languages *first*, before going into the details of vendor specific trigger features. There's a feature request *"Add procedural language abstraction API"*, in fact: [#6475](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6475)

This is being worked on for the upcoming version jOOQ 3.11, which will definitely support `BEGIN .. END` style blocks: [#6474](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/6474).

For jOOQ 3.10 and less, you will need to build your own jOOQ extension API based on the plain SQL templating mechanism documented here:

https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating

You don't need too much plumbing to get that functionality working...

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can do that, but you can use instead `ExecuteListeners`, which can be considered as triggers and you can do something similar that what you build with your SQL.

You can check out their documentation regarding [ExecuteListeners](https://www.jooq.org/doc/3.10/manual/sql-execution/execute-listeners/), they also provide a few example, like query statistics listener, logging listener and so forth.

They recommend extending `DefaultExecuteListener` and start from their with [Javadoc](https://www.jooq.org/javadoc/3.3.x/org/jooq/impl/DefaultExecuteListener.html), they have quite a variety of methods that you can override. I am pretty sure you will find what you need.

Comment: Is there any background/motivation why such a trivial thing is not supported i. e. why should I write Java code if there is an SQL for this? Originally, I wanted to write some own SQL builder, then I found jOOQ so I was happy there is an existing solution, but now I rethinking my original intent.

Comment: I am sorry, but I am not a maintainer of the project, so, for feature requests, you will want to go on their github to ask about this. If you look over their fluent api, they have quite a lot of methods that are "fluent". Just because the `createTrigger` method does not exists probably is not a deal breaker for most peole, since not too many people use sql triggers anyway. But hey, I am pretty sure, if you make a ticket on jooq github page and suggest this feature, they will gladly help you

Comment: In 10 years of jOOQ existence, this is actually the first time someone asked for this functionality, so indeed, I don't think this was a deal breaker thus far (given that the [plain SQL workaround has always been available](https://www.jooq.org/doc/latest/manual/sql-building/plain-sql-templating/)). Nor do I think you should write your own SQL builder ;-). In any case, I would definitely not recommend replacing actual SQL triggers by `ExecuteListener` *in general* (although that might be a viable solution in specific cases). A trigger really belongs into the database.

Comment: @LukasEder you suggest I update my answer to not include `ExecuteListener` and provide the plain SQL information instead?

Comment: No, that's not my suggestion for your answer. That's my suggestion for most people reading this answer. `ExecuteListener` may be a viable solution to the use-case you had in mind. But pretty surely, it isn't a viable solution to the problem the OP had in mind.